# gene transformation from plant to plant - transgenic plant

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, botany, molecular-genetics

I want to know if the expression of a transfered gene depends on source of the gene, if e.g.:

**1]** I isolate a gene from plant and transfered it to the same plant?

**2]** I isolate a gene that is *highly* expressed in plant, and transfer it to another plant ?

**3]** I isolate a gene that is *lowly* expressed in plant and transfered it to another plant

Is there a difference between the expression of the transferred gene in these three cases? What does the expression of the transfered gene depend on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many factors that could influence in the level of expression of a gene, but the two most important are the promoter and the place where your gene has introduce in the genome of de recevier plant.The first one, the promoter depends of the original expression of the original plant, if the expression was high in the original plant, it will be in the receivier plant (if you include the promoter in the construction of the transferred gene and both plant are close in filogenetically).The second one,the place where your gene has introduce in the genome of de recevier plant is a matter of luck, if you use a Agrobacterium, if you gene was introduce in a heterochromatin region it won´t express.

Sorry for my bad english, hope I was useful